# Modal Scroll not the body scroll using CSS and HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have a scroll down/up in my modal not in body. For example if i have may textbox and labels the modal will have a scroll down. PS: The modal is working.

Here's the structure:

```
//script
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".call_modal").click(function(){
  $(".modal").fadeIn();
  $(".modal").fadeIn();
  $(".modal_main").show();
  $(".text").show();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".close").click(function(){
  $(".modal").fadeOut();
  $(".modal_main").fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>

//html
    <div class="modalcontainer">
        <a class="call_modal" style="cursor:pointer;">Show Modal</a>
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal_close close"></div>
            <div class="modal_main">
                <label>Enter Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="text_username" class="text_username">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS if you have any question in the design or flow, I don't know the syntax of the scroll down and up.

```
.modalcontainer
{
    text-align: center;
}
.modal
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  display:none;
}
.modal_close
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
}
.close
{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.modal_main
{
  width:50%;
  height:35em;
  background:#fff;
  z-index:4;
  position:fixed;
  top:2em;
  border-radius:4px;
  left:24%;
  display:none;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: .0s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: visible!important;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInRight{0%{opacity:0;-webkit-transform:translateX(20px)}100%{opacity:1;-webkit-transform:translateX(0)}}

button
{
padding:20px;
border-radius:5px;
background:#3399cc;
border:none;
font-size:20px;
color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: put the css in the question

Comment: just control `overflow` for body with JS on open/close. And add/delete `owerflow` for your modal.

Comment: @HenriqueOeckslerBertoldi done

Comment: what is the syntax? @SergeyGultyaev

Comment: @DaveSpencer `body { overflow: hidden;}` and `#modal-id { overflow: auto; }`. It's when you have opened modal. When you close it  - delete these styles.

Comment: I didnt get it, please explain it properly. Thankyou sergey

Comment: The modal markup in your question is incomplete, which is obvious when the indenting is fixed. Is that the same as you're using, or did you just leave something out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with overflow propertie css?

```
.modal { overflow-y: scroll; }
```

Comment: the body will have an scroll down, but the modal has not.

Answer (score 0):

hm,
I wonder why you stick two fixed elements inside each other. A fixed positioned element is like a post it on your monitor. It's not in the page flow anymore. Wouldn't you want one container to be fixed and all inside to be in the normal flow again?

I just rebuilt it on codepen to look more into it. .modal only needs a `display: block`. Some adjustments to .modal and the animation makes it probably more predictable. Also, you should have an eye on the vendor prefixes. At least offer those properties without prefix, too.

```
.modal_main {
    width: 50%;
    max-height: 90vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5vh;
    border-radius: 4px;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    /* -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important; */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInRight;
    bottom: 5vh;
}
```

You might want to peek into https://codepen.io/nulllinie/pen/dzBOzO